# Read plain python object from file

Tags: python, object, plaintext

Our client provided us with text files containing the following data:

```
{'op-code-gtm-gtm2-count': {'Label': 'op-code-gtm-gtm2-count', 'Datapoints': [{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 17, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Sum': 79792.0,....
```

Note that it's a default python object, and not a json one (else we'd be using `json.load(file)`).
Any suggestions on how we could create a python object from reading this file ?

Comment: It's not just a Python object literal, it's *partial Python code* (`datetime(...)`, `tzlocal()`). You should request the data in some more neutral format if at all possible…

Comment: That's also my opinion, but I was curious whether it was possible programmatically.
Copy/paste is also an option, but tedious!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend suggested this solution:

```
import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone as tzlocal

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
   st = f.read()
   data = eval(st)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That can give different results based on location or time.

Comment: That's true, but it works fine since it just shifts the time amongst all the data points in the same fashion. For our use case, this is sufficient!

Answer (score -1):

Using eval is the easiest way to do this, read the text file into a string then do this:

```
obj = eval(datastring.replace(", tzinfo=tzlocal()", "")
```

Since the datetime part isn't valid python code due to the `tzinfo` part being undefined you can just replace it with nothing to avoid parsing that bit. This fix will only work if all the data is formatted in the same way obviously.

However it seems easier and cleaner trying to get the input sent in a more friendly format. Either as a pure python object or JSON.

Comment: This doesn't work with `datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 17, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal())`.

Comment: also both `eval` and `literal_eval` will raise Exceptions for invalid syntax, the key difference is that `literal_eval` is safer, evaluating only certain python expressions/literal structures rather than all arbitrary code

Comment: @deceze I've edited it so it will work with `datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 17, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal())`

Comment: How so? Removing `tzlocal()` still leaves the `datetime()` call, and probably other such calls in the rest of the data.

Comment: @deceze `eval` creates a datetime object out of the `datetime()` call. `eval("datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 17, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal())".replace(", tzinfo=tzlocal()", ""))` runs completely fine. However yes other calls in the input may cause problems but that is the only one provided in the question.